# Random projection with compressive sensing and hashing algorithms

Tags: sampling, transform, compressive-sensing, random

I read that Random Projection matrices can be used in both Compressive Sensing and Locality Sensitive Hashing. I need simple explanation for the difference between applying Random Projection in both cases?
For Compressive Sensing, I know that the Random Projection Matrix must satisfy the RIP property. Less coherence (low autocorrelation ) between the columns of the Random Projection Matrix must be satisfied. Is the same requirement needed in  case of Locality Sensitive Hashing?
Are there any other requirements which need to be achieved in the Random Projection Matrix?
In case of Compressive Sensing, the transform is reversible, and the original signal can be reconstructed from the compressed one. What about Random Projection with Locality Sensitive Hashing? Is it reversible?

Comment: The restricted isometry property means that for sparse signals, the CS matrix is an distance preserving embedding, which I imagine is similar to what is happening in LSH.

Comment: I agree with you. Then, why RIP is only mentioned with compressive sensing, and when taking about LSH, the condition required for the Random Projection Matrix is to be orthonormal?

Comment: Again, I don't have any experience with LSH, but if LSH doesn't assume sparsity, you'd need a proper Isometry, not just RIP.